# Is trailing semicolon optional in expression sequencing?

Tags: ocaml

```ml
let t =
  let a = 1 in
  ();
  let b = 2 in
  a + b;
```

This Ocaml code works well. Note that trailing semicolon after `a + b`

According to Ocaml [express sequencing](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/expr.html#sss:expr-sequence), Ocaml defines syntax of sequencing to alternating sequence of expression and semicolon. for example `<expr>;<expr>;<expr>...`
So, I expect compile error, But It didn't.
Why this code works well?

added:
I want to understand how It's excutable by interpreter eventhough Its semantics(trailing `;`) dosen't specified in Ocaml(Maybe I just couldn't found)

I think one of the following cases happens

1. The Ocaml parser ignore `;` for the convenient of developer
2. There is syntactic sugar for trailing `;` in expression sequencing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note, the code you've shown parses as:

```
let t =
  let a = 1 in
  (
    ();
    let b = 2 in
    a + b;
  )
```

It's much more idiomatic to simply write:

```
let t =
  let a = 1 in
  let b = 2 in
  a + b
```

That `();` does nothing.

Now, that trailing semicolon works in *some* scenarios, when the syntax makes it non-ambiguous. But let's put another definition after that definition of `t`.

```
# let t =
    let a = 1 in
    ();
    let b = 2 in
    a + b;
  let x = 42;;
Error: Syntax error
```

The parser is looking for an expression to come after that `;` but doesn't find it. OCaml doesn't consider the whitespace syntactically significant and doesn't care what we think indentation means.

Be careful about this. But, the trailing semicolon *may* be useful when doing things like defining record fields. If we always have a trailing semi-colon, we don't have to obsess over removing one if we add another field. E.g.

```
# type t = {
    x : int;
    y : int;
  };;
type t = { x : int; y : int; }
# type t = {
    x : int;
    y : int
  };;
type t = { x : int; y : int; }
```

Note that both definitions do the same thing.

Comment: "The parser is looking for an expression to come after that `;` but doesn't find it"
Does it mean The Ocaml parser ignores `;` in this case for the convenience of developer?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by ignored by the parser: the trailing `;` is read by the parser, but as an optional element, it is discarded when building the AST. In other words, trailing semicolon are purely a syntactic decoration without any semantics.

Answer (score 0):

`ocamlformat` formats this code like this :

```ml
let t =
  let a = 1 in
  ();
  let b = 2 in
  a + b
```

Notice that there is no semicolon trailing the `a + b` expression.
I believe this is because it is the last expression being evaluated so there is no need to put an extra `;` since there is no expression left to be evaluated.